# Ist "Rock" auch ein Synonym für "Anzug"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, synonym

Ich habe mehrmals in Bücher gesehen, dass "der Rock" fast wie ein Synonym von Anzug benutzt ist. Ein Beispiel:

> "Er riss seinen Überzieher auf und ich sah zu meinem Entsetzen, dass er weder Hemd noch Rock anhatte und den Mantel über der nackten Haut trug." ("Der Golem", Gustav Meyrink).

Als ich meiner Lehrerin "Ich werde zur Hochzeit keinen Rock tragen" gesagt habe, hat sie mir korrigiert, indem sie mir gesagt hat, dass "der Rock" nur als weibliches Kleidungstück benutzt wird.

Ich habe ein bisschen gesucht:

- https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/Rock?bidir=1  => hier sagt dass die Meinung als "Anzug" nur in der Schweiz benutzt ist (aber Meyrink war kein Schweizer)
- https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rock => hier scheint es zu bestätigen, dass man "Rock" in der Sinn von "Anzug" benutzen kann

Meine Frage: kann man "Rock" als Synonym für "Anzug" benutzen? Ist es mundartlich (oder Schweizerdeutsch)? Ist es eine alte Form, die nicht mehr in der Umgangssprache benutzt wird?

Comment: _"Ist es eine alte Form, die nicht mehr in der Umgangssprache benutzt wird?"_ Genau das.

Comment: Es ist eine veraltete Verwendung. _Der Golem_ ist ja auch schon ungefähr 100 Jahre alt.

Comment: @user Nächstes mal. Normalerweise mache ich das.

Comment: Die alte Bezeichnung ist noch in der Redewendung "Das Hemd ist mir näher als der Rock" gebräuchlich. In älterer Literatur ist es aber gängig aber wirkt anfangs befremdlich. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zunächst einmal ist anzumerken, dass ein *Rock* nicht ausschließlich „[…] nur als weibliches Kleidungsstück benutzt wird.“ Es gibt auch verschiedenste Arten von [*Männerröcken*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A4nnerrock), wie zum Beispiel *Kilts*, *Schottenröcke*, *Zottenröcke*, *Sarongs* und dergleichen.

Dann gibt es noch den sogenannten [*Herrenrock*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herrenrock) und dessen Spätform: den [*Gehrock*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gehrock). Dabei handelt es sich um doppelreihige Jacken mit knielangem, angesetztem Schoß. Heute sind sie aus der Mode gekommen, dennoch würde man sie optisch den *Anzügen* zuordnen. Doch gerade bei Herren- bzw. Gehröcken würde ich selbst aufgrund der Verwechslungsgefahr nicht die Verkürzung *Rock* verwenden.

Comment: Danke schön für die Antwort, jetzt ist es klar! Ja, und du hast Recht, ich hatte die Männerröcken vergessen

Comment: Auch der Priesterrock.

Comment: [Dagobert Duck trägt ebenfalls einen Gehrock](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagobert_Duck#Äußeres)

Comment: Ja, Leute, wir können jetzt noch sämtliche Rockarten einzeln aufzählen und wer wann welchen trägt oder getragen hat hier auflisten, aber dazu sind Kommentare eigentlich nicht da.

Answer (score 6):

Als ich noch ein Kind war (geboren 1965), war es zumindest im Osten Österreichs allgemein üblich, Sakkos als *Röcke* zu bezeichnen. Das Wort *Sakko* kannte ich als Kind gar nicht. Ich lernte das Wort "Sakko" erst mit rund 17 oder 18 Jahren kennen, als in der Tanzschule die Begriffe *Rock* und *Sakko* abwechselnd und synonym verwendet wurden. Kurz danach (1984), als ich beim Bundesheer war, war der *Rock* ein Teil der Uniform. Und mein Vater (Jahrgang 1933) spricht auch heute noch davon, seinen Rock anzuziehen, wenn er sein Sakko meint.

Die Begriffe *Herrenrock* und *Gehrock* wurden dort, wo ich aufgewachsen bin, nie verwendet. Ich kenne diese Wörter nur aus literarischen Werken.

Der Rock war niemals der ganze Anzug, sondern nur der Oberteil, mit Jacke bzw. Sakko vergleichbar. Ein Rock hat lange Ärmel, gehört zur Outdoor-Oberbekleidung, reicht bis zur Hüfte hinunter und bedeckt etwa die Hälfte des Gesäßes.

Eine Verwechslung mit dem üblicherweise von Frauen getragenen Kleidungsstück, das man heute *Rock* nennt, war in meiner Kindheit übrigens ausgeschlossen. Das was die Frauen da trugen nannte man "die Schoß". Dieses Wort dürfte aber nur ein relativ kleines Verbreitungsgebiet gehabt haben (zumindest aber Südosten der Steiermark und Südburgenland), denn schon in Wien scheint dieses Wort unbekannt zu sein. (Jedenfalls kannte keiner meiner Wiener Kollegen dieses Wort als ich 1997 dorthin übersiedelt bin.) Das Wort *»die Schoß«* ist, soweit mir das bekannt ist, heute nirgendwo mehr in Verwendung.

Comment: Ich kenne _Rock_ und _Schoß_ in den genannten Bedeutungen von meiner Oma (aus Kärnten).

Comment: Zu allem Überfluss gibt es natürlich auch noch Rockschöße.